# Durante las pruebas, la instancia de una clase devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mocha

Un poco de contexto.

> Estoy creando un *plugin* usando pruebas y al usar la instancia de una clase, simplemente no pasa la prueba mas simple.
>
> El plugin es una *copia adaptada* del [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) un conocido módulo de [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) que gestiona la acreditación por medio de *tokens*. La adaptación consiste en convertirlo en un *plugin* de [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js), usar [axios](/questions/tagged/axios) para la conexión al servidor y [localforage](/questions/tagged/localforage) para el almacenamiento persistente. Además, estoy practicando el desarrollo basado en pruebas (TDD por sus siglas en inglés).

### El plugin

La estructura del plugin es mas o menos así:

```
index.js                    // punto de entrada
  |
  ---> acreditar.js         // contiene la clase VueAcreditacion
          |
          ---> opciones.js  // contiene las opciones basicas por defecto
```

Este archivo de opciones, es un objeto que contiene la lista de propiedades, por ejemplo:

```
export default {
  tokenName: 'token'
}
```

Y este archivo se carga en el archivo de la clase, `acreditar.js`, que contiene solo lo básico:

```
import opcionesBasicas from './opciones'

export default class VueAcreditacion {
  constructor() {
    let _opciones = opcionesBasicas

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      opciones: {
        get: () => _opciones
      }
    })
  }
}
```

En mi archivo de pruebas, importo mis dependencias, incluyendo el plugin; para poder instalarlo en la instancia de Vue.

```
let Vue = require('vue')
let expect = require('chai').expect
const plugin = require('../src/plugin/index')
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(plugin)
let vm = new Vue()
```

Por último, el archivo `index.js` que es donde se crea el plugin, se carga este archivo y se crea la instancia de `VueAcreditacion`.

```
import opcionesBasicas from './opciones'

export default class VueAcreditacion {
  constructor() {
    let _opciones = opcionesBasicas

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      opciones: {
        get: () => _opciones
      }
    })
  }
}
```

> En este momento, si arranco el servidor de desarrollo y veo mi plantilla con `{{ this.$acreditar.opciones.tokenName }}` veo `token` en la pantalla. Ergo, el plugin funciona.

### Las pruebas

Cuando se instala un plugin correctamente, VueJS le coloca una propiedad `installed` automáticamente, así que mi prueba es correcta:

```
describe('El plugin', () => {
  it('debe estar instalado', () => {
    console.log(plugin)
    expect(plugin.installed).to.be.true
  })
})
```

La siguiente prueba, donde verifico la propiedad `$acreditar.opciones.tokenName` **falla**.

```
describe('La propiedad `$acreditar.opciones.tokenName', () => {
  it('debe devolver `token`', () => {
    const NOMBRE = 'token'
    expect(plugin.$acreditar.opciones.tokenName).to.be.equal(NOMBRE)
  })
})
```

Este es el reporte, con todo y gato

```
 1   -_-_,------,
 1   -_-_|   /\_/\
 0   -_-^|__( x .x)
     -_-  ""  ""

  1 passing (23ms)
  1 failing

  1) La opción `$acreditar.opciones.tokenName debe devolver `token`:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'opciones' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/index.spec.js:54:12)
```

Como dice que `opciones` no está definido, verifico si `$acreditar` si existe:

```
describe('El plugin', () => {
  it('debe tener la propiedad $acreditar', () => {
    expect(plugin.$acreditar).to.not.be.undefined
  })
})
```

Pero sigue fallando:

```
  1) El plugin debe tener la propiedad $acreditar:
     AssertionError: expected undefined not to be undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/index.spec.js:34:5)
```

Dado que el plugin funciona como se espera en las condiciones de uso pero falla en las pruebas, supongo que algo estoy haciendo mal en mis pruebas.

## Problema

¿Estoy escribiendo mal mis pruebas o está mal mi plugin? ¿Cuál es el problema, cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Agradecería enormemente si me proporcionan información, enlaces, etc., que me ayude a comprender el origen del problema y a evitar su recurrencia.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Estás usando la versión 1? Porque en Vue.js 2 la manera de crear un plugin es por medio del método `install`, el cual recibe dos parámetros: el constructor de Vue y el objeto de opciones. Es en éste método en donde puedes agregar propiedades/funciones a Vue directamente a su constructor o como instancia (agregado directamente al prototipo de Vue). Según tengo entendido, `Vue` es el que debería tener `$acreditar`.

Comment: Estaba usando mal la `vm`. Al rato escribo una guía para hacer pruebas con VueJS.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer pruebas correctamente en Vue se debe crear **una instancia** de Vue, previamente configurada. Es decir, en el archivo de pruebas, cargamos los archivos necesarios para correr las pruebas:

```
let Vue = require('vue')
let expect = require('chai').expect
const plugin = require('../src/plugin/index')
```

configuramos Vue, en este ejemplo, para que no mande el consejo

```
mensajeVue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(plugin)
```

y procedemos a crear **la instancia** de vue

```
let vm = new Vue()
```

En esta instancia ya está el plugin y podemos hacer las pruebas que hayamos diseñado, por ejemplo:

```
describe('El archivo plugin', function () {
  it('debe existir', function () {
    expect(plugin).to.not.be.undefined
  })

  it('debe estar instalado', () => {
    expect(plugin.installed).to.be.true
  })

  it('debe tener la propiedad $acreditar', () => {
    expect(vm.$acreditar).to.not.be.undefined
  })

  it('debe tener la propiedad version', () => {
    const version = '0.1.0'
    expect(vm.$acreditar.version).to.equal('0.1.0')
  })
})
```

Comment: Esto era a lo que me refería en mi comentario ;)