# Cómo probar el funcionamiento correcto de promesas con mocha y chai

Tags: javascript, promesas, pruebas-unitarias, mocha, chai

Sigo practicando el desarrollo basado en pruebas (o basado en conductas)<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> y tengo problemas con pasar las pruebas que devuelven promesas.

La función<sup><sup>2</sup></sup> que quiero probar es esta:

```
login(credenciales, opciones){
  opciones = {
    "url":"http://sgc-server.dev/auth/login/",
    "data": {"username":"admin","password":"abc123"},
    "method":"POST"
  }

  return axios(opciones).then(function (respuesta) {
    this.setToken(respuesta)
    return respuesta
  })
}
```

Configuro [correctamente mi batería de pruebas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62345/durante-las-pruebas-la-instancia-de-una-clase-devuelve-undefined) y preparo las pruebas para esta función.

Primero verifico la función `setItem`:

```
it('debe tener la función setToken()', function () {
  expect(vm.$acreditar.setToken).to.be.a('function')
})
```

Luego verifico que `login` sea efectivamente una función:

```
it('Debe existir', function () {
  expect(vm.$acreditar.login).to.be.a('function')
})
```

Y luego empiezan mis problemas.

Según la [documentación de Chai](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) **no debo** usar la función `done()` (aunque yo te todas formas lo hago y siempre pasa):

```
it('debe devolver el token, parte I', function(done){
  let token = vm.$acreditar.login(_credenciales)
  done()
  return token.should.eventually.equal('auth_token')
})
```

La misma documentación recomienda que debo usar algo como esto `return doSomethingAsync().should.eventually.equal("foo");` y eso hago:

```
it('debe devolver el token, parte II', function () {
  let promesa = vm.$acreditar.login(_credenciales)
  return promesa().should.eventually.equal('auth_token')
})
```

Chia dice que cuando no se pueda usar `return` podemos usar la función `done` que proporciona el framework, aunque mocha o chai no proporcionan esta función:

```
it('debe devolver el token, parte III', function () {
  vm.$acreditar.login(_credenciales).should.eventually.equal('auth_token').notify(done)
})
```

Asi que pruebo directamente llamando a la función y después de tres segundo, regresa con un mensaje de error:

```
it('debe devolver el token, parte IV', function () {
  return vm.$acreditar.login(_credenciales).should.eventually.equal('auth_token')
})
```

Estos son los resultados de las pruebas:

```
La función login()
  ✓ Debe existir
  ✓ debe tener un local storage
  ✓ debe devolver el token, parte I
  1) debe devolver el token, parte II
  2) debe devolver el token, parte III
  3) debe devolver el token, parte IV


3 passing (3s)
12 pending
3 failing

1) La función login() debe devolver el token, parte II:
   TypeError: promesa is not a function
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/index.spec.js:98:12)

2) La función login() debe devolver el token, parte III:
   ReferenceError: done is not defined
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/index.spec.js:102:85)

3) La función login() debe devolver el token, parte IV:
   Error: Timeout of 3000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, 
          ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

### Pregunta

Puedo confirmar, sin lugar a dudas, que la función funciona, así que descarto errores de programación **en la función `login()`**, de comunicación con el servidor o de configuración de `mocha`.

#### ¿Cómo debo escribir las pruebas usando mocha y chai para verificar una función que devuelve una promesa?

---

<sup>1</sup> ... y sigo sin entender como funcionan las promesas
<sup>2</sup> La función **si funciona**, lo sé porque puedo ver en el localStorage el token, *cuando uso el plugin en un componente de VueJS*.

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Quizas debas hacer primero la llamada asíncrona y asignar el resultado a una variable, para despues realizar la aserción a esa variable, mocha tiene las funciones before y beforeEach que se ejecutan antes de cada prueba, en ellas podrías ejecutar el método login y asignar el resultado a una variable. Ademas de que creo que el return de tu mñetodo login debería ser un callback

```
var token = null;
before (done, reject) {
  vm.$acreditar.login(_credenciales, opciones, function (responseLogin) {
    token = responseLogin
    done()
  })
}

it('debe devolver el token, parte I', function(done){
  token.should.equal('auth_token')      
})
```

Y tu método login debería ejecutar el callback pasado como parámetro en lugar de hacer un return

```
login(credenciales, opciones, callback){
  opciones = {
    "url":"http://sgc-server.dev/auth/login/",
    "data": {"username":"admin","password":"abc123"},
    "method":"POST"
  }

  return axios(opciones).then(function (respuesta) {
    this.setToken(respuesta)
    callback(respuesta)
  })
}
```